# How to pass attribute value to function that is used in a directive template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to build a reusable autocomplete textfield component. At the moment I can't make it reusable, there can be only 1 instance.

This is the template:

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
<form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
    <md-autocomplete
            ng-disabled="isDisabled"
            md-selected-item="selectedItem"
            md-search-text-change="searchTextChange(searchText)"
            md-search-text="searchText"
            md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)"
            md-items="item in querySearch(searchText, dataArray)"
            md-item-text="item.display"
            md-min-length="0"
            placeholder="{{placeholderText}}">
        <md-item-template>
            <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
    </md-autocomplete>
</form>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController" layout="column" ng-cloak>
    <auto-complete a = "{{data1}}"></auto-complete>
    <auto-complete a = "{{data2}}"></auto-complete>
</div>
```

The only part that is customizable is data, which is a string array.

This is controller and directive:

```
angular
.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('myController',['$scope', '$timeout','$q', '$log', function($scope, $timeout, $q, $log) {
    $scope.simulateQuery = false;
    $scope.isDisabled    = false;
    // assign the data
    $scope.data1        = loadDataArray();
    $scope.querySearch   = querySearch;
    $scope.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
    $scope.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;
    $scope.placeholderText = "Choose a state";
    $scope.data2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    $scope.dataArray = [];

    function querySearch (query, data) {
        var results = query ? data.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : data, deferred;
        if ($scope.simulateQuery) {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                    deferred.resolve( results );
                },
                Math.random() * 1000, false);
            return deferred.promise;
        } else {
            return results;
        }
    }

    //filter function for search query
    function createFilterFor(query) {
        var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
        return function filterFn(record) {
            return (record.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
        };
    }

    // Run this function each time search text is changed
    function searchTextChange(text) {
        $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
    }
    // Run this function each time a new item is selected
    function selectedItemChange(item) {
        $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
    }
    //build list of states as map of key-value pairs
    function loadDataArray() {
        var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
             Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
             Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
             Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
             North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
             South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
             Wisconsin, Wyoming';
        return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {
            return {
                value: state.toLowerCase(),
                display: state
            };
        });
    }
}]).directive('autoComplete', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
             scope.dataArray = attr.a;
        },
        templateUrl: "temp.html",
        replace: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I modified under directive like this:

```
return {
    scope: true,
    restrict: "E",
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
         scope.dataArray = attr.a;
    },
    templateUrl: "temp.html",
    replace: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the directive like this.

```
.directive('autoComplete', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            'data' : '=a'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
             scope.dataArray = scope.data;
        },
        templateUrl: "temp.html",
        replace: true
    }
});
```